# JavaScript in function Date var argument changes for no reason?

Tags: javascript, function, date

Noob here. Sorry if the question is stupid.
I'm writing a script for travel purpose.
I need to get dates of departure start and end given the day of the week.
And dates for returns given the offset of start/end date;
After calling function departure start date is also changing.
I can't comprehend my error. Please help.

```js
var departstart = getNextDayOfTheWeek(3, 0);
console.log("Departure from " + departstart);
var departend = getNextDayOfTheWeek(3, 0);
console.log("Departure to " + departend);
var returnstart = getoffday(3, departstart);
// check again depature
console.log("Departure from " + departstart);
// Has changed?!?!?!
console.log("Return from " + returnstart);
var returnend = getoffday(3, departstart);
console.log("Return to " + returnend);

// Gets a date of next day of the week
function getNextDayOfTheWeek(dayOfWeek, excludeToday = true, refDate = new Date()) {

    refDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    refDate.setDate(refDate.getDate() + +!!excludeToday +
        (dayOfWeek + 7 - refDate.getDay() - +!!excludeToday) % 7);
    return (refDate);

}

// Gets a date of diff day from given date
function getoffday(diff = 0, workyday = new Date()) {
    console.log("Inside function before execution " + workyday);
    workyday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    workyday.setDate(workyday.getDate() + diff);
    console.log("Inside function after execution " + workyday);
    return (workyday);
}
```

I've thought may be I should not use argument in function and define local var, but that did not help.

Comment: The Date functions **modify** the date, so when you pass a date into `getoffday()` it changes.

Comment: I get that. But isn't workyday should be used as a local variable if passed as a parameter?

Comment: No, the date is passed to the function as a reference, and a copy of the date is not made unless your code explicitly makes a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to modify a certain date all the time (as it is right now), you could e.g. modify your `getoffday` function as follows:

```
// Gets a date of diff day from given date
function getoffday(diff=0, workyday = new Date()) {
    // we create a new Date object with the value of the provided "workyday" param
    // now we modify only this copied date - the provided date does not change
    const dateCopy = new Date(workyday.getTime());
    console.log("Inside function before execution " + dateCopy);
    dateCopy.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    dateCopy.setDate(dateCopy.getDate() + diff);
    console.log("Inside function after execution " + dateCopy);
    return (dateCopy);
}
```

Of course, you could use the same method for your `getNextDayOfTheWeek` function. This way you get isolated results (no influence of variable values outside your function).

Comment: That's what I thought in the first place. But it didn't work for some reason. 1) Why you used const? Is it allowed to be modified by setDate?   2) Why would a function change the parameter instead of returning a value of itself with given return?